# Assigning custom properties automatically

Tags: python, objects, properties, data-blocks

I have been looking at some add-ons written by other users, and noticed that on startup, every object in the scene has custom properties defined automatically, even if the addon is never actually used. How do I go about adding this functionality  to my own add-on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register the property per data type you want (Object, Camera, Light...) in `register()`.

```
def register():
    
    # Object property
    bpy.types.Object.your_object_property = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    
    # Scene property
    bpy.types.Scene.your_scene_property = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    
    # Camera property
    bpy.types.Camera.your_camera_property = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    
    # Light property
    bpy.types.Light.your_light_property = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    
    #...

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Object.your_object_property
    del bpy.types.Scene.your_scene_property
    del bpy.types.Light.your_light_property
    del bpy.types.Camera.your_camera_property

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Don't forget to remove each property when `unregister()` is getting called.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! @Cod3R